# I am not clear How I can make the PHP Class file to have different output on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

```
$taxonomies = $post->taxonomies()->get();
```

but when I use 'echo' statement, it's result was string like the following.

```
echo $taxonomies[0];
// {"term_taxonomy_id":317,"term_id":317,"taxonomy":"skill","description":"","parent":0,"count":1,"pivot":{"object_id":4886,"term_taxonomy_id":317},"term":{"term_id":317,"name":"Consulting","slug":"consulting","term_group":0}}
```

but when I use 'print_r' statement, it's result was object like the following

```
print_r($taxonomies[0]);

Corcel\Model\Taxonomy Object
(
    [table:protected] => term_taxonomy
    [primaryKey:protected] => term_taxonomy_id
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => term
        )

    [timestamps] => 
    [postType:protected] => 
    [connection:protected] => wordpress
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
....
```

I am not clear how it works like this?

Comment: its a Model, when you try to convert it to a string it gets serialized to JSON, there is a whole section about serializing eloquent models in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is that `echo` converts object of some class to **string**. And you, as a developer, can control this process using [magic method `__toString`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

Diving deep in the code you can see that `Corcel\Model\Taxonomy` extends class, that in turn extends `lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. An in this class there's [`__toString` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78eb4dabcc03e189620c16f436358d41d31ae11f/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1638) which converts your object to json.

As for `print_r` - this function does not convert object to any other type, just outputs readable object representation.

Answer (score 0):

The one is JSON notation, the other is the dump of an instance in memory.

Use [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) or `json_enode()` for different output.